# Significance Test for values above/below μ±4σ

Tags: statistical-significance

I would like to ask when we have a variable X which is normally distributed with mean 0 and s.d 0.5 and we want to check if x>2 is statistically significant: 
so the z value would be 4 so in a standard normal distribution how can i find the area under the curve above the μ+4σ  value (because I cant find it on the tables).

Thanks

Comment: Could I just say that for example for threshold a=0,05-> z=1,645 and the my z value is much bigger so it falls above the threshold and it is not significant?

Comment: What are the null and alternative hypotheses, and why are you performing a test?

Comment: @Glen_b
Its a distribution of gene expression values. The thing is that I am confused because its a test based on one sample and I want to check if a specific value of gene expression is significant or not. I assume that I should do a z-test but I am not sure about the hypothesis. Could you please give some tips?

Comment: Could I do i z-test with H0: μ=2 and h1: μ>2?
It doesnt make sence. it looks like i test 2 samples

Comment: I cannot give any tips because I still have no idea what your hypotheses are (nor what you're trying to achieve). Can you please stop saying the word "significant" and actually describe what it is you're trying to do? None of the things you said make any sense to me.